# Azure App.Config SharedAccessSignature Error

Tags: wcf, azure, app-config

I am trying to create a WCF service.  Which will be authenticated by Windows Azure Service Bus.

My app.config is like below

```
<tokenProvider>
<sharedAccessSignature keyName="" key=""/>
</tokenProvider>
```

While running WCF in WCF test client I am getting below error.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element 'sharedAccessSignature'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following example illustrates how to create a WCF service that can be reached through a Service Bus relay:

Define the service like this in the .svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ProblemSolver" CodeBehind="ProblemSolver.svc.cs" %>
```

Note that **ProblemSolver** implements an interface named **IProblemSolver** that specifies the service contract.

The relevant parts of my web.config file look like this:

```
<configuration>
...
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="sharedAccessSignatureClientCredentials">
        <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
          <tokenProvider>
            <sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="[YourSharedAccessSignature]" />
          </tokenProvider>
        </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpRelayBinding>
      <binding name="default" />
    </netTcpRelayBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="ProblemSolver">
      <endpoint address="sb://[YourServiceBusNamespace].servicebus.windows.net/solver" behaviorConfiguration="sharedAccessSignatureClientCredentials"
        binding="netTcpRelayBinding" bindingConfiguration="default"
        name="RelayEndpoint" contract="IProblemSolver" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <extensions>
    ...
  </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
...
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have a WCF service which can be hosted in IIS.
Your below code is for self hosting WCF like console app.
Uri address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "[YourServiceBusNamespace]", "solver");
  ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProblemSolver), address);

I want my existing in-house WCF service to exposed through azure service bus.